# Mongoid in rails not saving document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I'm using rails 4.2.5 with mongoid 5.1.0 on windows 10 in dev mode. I have created a model "Signup" but it won't save to MongoDB. I can see that rails connects to MongoDB but no transactions are performned.

What am I missing?

Model code:

```
class Signup
    include Mongoid::Document

    field :email, type: String
    field :date, type: DateTime, default: ->{ Time.now }

end
```

Console tests:

```
irb(main):034:0> s = Signup.create
=> #<Signup _id: 57b9d0436fc5511c04a945ce, email: nil, date: 2016-08-21 16:01:07 UTC>
irb(main):035:0> Signup.count
=> 0
irb(main):036:0> s.save!
=> true
irb(main):037:0> Signup.count
=> 0
irb(main):038:0>
```

Answer (score 0):

found the solution, I used a dot in the database name in mongoid.yml (project.io) which somehow hindered db creation. I removed it (project_io) and everything is working now as it should.